# mysql select performance (many variables with index vs less vaiables with index)

Tags: mysql, performance, variables, select, indexing

I have a select query which one has many conditional variables in it and all are indexed and second one has less indexed conditional variables. the main conditional ones are the ones within ** XX **  and the rest are optional. can you suggest which one could result to faster and better query please.

I just need to know if it is good to pass more optional indexed conditional variables vs less.

```
1)     SELECT  *
    FROM  tableX
    WHERE  city_id = :city_id
      AND  category_id = :category_id
      AND  type_id = :type_id
      AND  **valid_date** > :date_now
      AND  (**N_lat** BETWEEN :sw_lat AND :ne_lat )
      AND  (**E_lng** BETWEEN :sw_lng AND :ne_lng )
      AND  (**price_deposit** BETWEEN :min_deposit AND :max_deposit )
      AND  (**price_rent** BETWEEN :min_rent AND :max_rent )
    ORDER BY  $colomnX DESC 

2)     SELECT  *
    FROM  tableX
    WHERE  **valid_date** > :date_now
      AND  (**N_lat** BETWEEN :sw_lat AND :ne_lat )
      AND  (**E_lng** BETWEEN :sw_lng AND :ne_lng )
      AND  (**price_deposit** BETWEEN :min_deposit AND :max_deposit )
      AND  (**price_rent** BETWEEN :min_rent AND :max_rent )
    ORDER BY  $colomnX DESC
```

Comment: use EXPLAIN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: more conditions = more comparisons, which will eat more cpu. you can't get around that. on the other hand, the cost of actually fetching matched records from storage may outweigh the costs of the comparisons, so reducing fetch requirements by eliminating more records early can help. but in general, there is NO way for us to answer this. it depends entirely on your index structure, and how your db performs.

Comment: Thank, I would be thinking of reducing the index by eliminating more optional variables in order to save more cpu but i was not sure if this may result for mysql to read of more records by reducing the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query 1:  This is the optimal index:

```
INDEX(city_id, category_id, type_id, one-more-thing)
```

The first three fields can be in any order, the 4th can be any of the other fields being "range" tested.

Query 2:  Either of these is likely to be benefical:

```
INDEX(any-one-of-the-columns-mentioned-in-WHERE)
INDEX($columnX)
```

As for *which* column to index, well, it is hard to predict.  You could make single-column indexes for each of them, and let the optimizer pick dynamically.

Mentioning two columns that are in "range" tests is almost never useful in an index.  The optimizer may use the first one, but won't use the second.

Query 2 is likely to deliver more rows than Query 1, so it does not make sense to compare them.

More discussion in [my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).